# How is the second for loop output 4. Shouldn't it be 3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```js
var arr = [[1, ], [2], [3]];
var product = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  product = i; //output: 2 (which makes sense)
};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  product += i; //output: 4 (shouldn't the output 3?)
};
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? You will understand why.

Comment: If I just copy your code my output of the second product is 5?

Comment: Actually the final value of `product` is `5`.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare a surprising amount of people don't know how to debug or use breakpoints. It's amazing really. Should be the first thing to learn imo.

Comment: Also, please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, **Introduce the problem before you post any code**. -- _In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible._

Comment: @TKoL you are perfectly right. It should be the first thing to learn after "Hello World"  :-):-) .

Comment: @TKoL but eslint throws an error every time I write `debugger` :P

Comment: Do you run the second loop after running the first loop or without running the first loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your product starts at 1. If it started at zero, the product would be three. Assuming that only the second loop is running.

If the first loop is running as well, then I would expect the result to be 5. Since product = 2 after the first loop, then 0 + 1 + 2 is added from the second loop for a total of 5.

Comment: @bruno his answer makes sense, assuming that you OP actually meant for the second loop to run WITHOUT the first loop running (which might actually be what OP meant).

Comment: @TKoL in that case Hannah N must edit her answer to indicate clearly the code she supposes, which is not the OP code

Comment: @TKoL so you was right, you are a gentleman giving credit to an answer in a question you also answer

Comment: He really is. Especially when his answer demonstrates the solution much more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var arr = [[1,],[2],[3]];
var product = 1;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  product = i; //output: 2 (which makes sense)
};



for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  product += i; //output: 4 (shouldn't the output 3?)
};

console.log(product);
```

It's 5 after the final loop. `product` is equal to 2 after running the first loop, then you do +0, +1, +2. 2 + 1 + 2 is 5.

Answer (score 1):

in the first loop you get length of your array with nested arrays inside.
so, your output is equal : 2 (array has 3 elements, but their index starts from 0, so, 0-1-2.. you got 2)

```
var arr = [[1, ], [2], [3]];
var product = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  product = i; //output: 2 (which makes sense)
};
```

then you have product, where your initial value 1 was rewrited to value 2.

So, when you run second loop, you currently increment parent = 2 + 0 + 1 + 2 (but not 3, because it don't feets loop conditions)

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  product += i; //output: 4 (shouldn't the output 3?)
};
```

So, this is the way you getting final result of parent that equals 2.